# ASP.NET Web Forms - Model View Presenter and user controls

Tags: asp.net, webforms, mvp

I'm new to using the MVP pattern and I just want to make sure on the best way to call a presenter from within a user control.

*MyPage.aspx* has a presenter *MyPresenter*

The page contains a user control which accepts MyPage's Presenter via a property which I setup from MyPage

```
MyUserControl.Presenter = this.Presenter
```

I'm now trying to call *Method1* within the presenter which retrieves some config and sets it on the view from the user control.

```
Presenter.Method1(); // calls method and sets config to the view
```

My question is firstly

1. should I be using the presenter in the user control in this way?
2. If so, is it valid to be accessing the view value via the user control as shown below.

   Presenter.View.MyData

I just want to make sure I'm not going off down the completely wrong path with this!

Comment: Have you read this article: http://haacked.com/archive/2006/08/09/ASP.NETSupervisingControllerModelViewPresenterFromSchematicToUnitTestsToCode.aspx ?

Comment: I have just had a read but still not sure that answers my question. Good read though.

Comment: Yea, I'm not experienced enough here to be comfortable answering your question but I thought it might help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What I use to do is to have one presenter for each user control which is responsible only for the user control presentation and one presenter for each page (.aspx).
I think keeping things separated helps also for maintaining as you will have "skinny" presenter which are responsible only of a small section of the UI.
The user control will be also "self-contained" in the way that you can reuse them as the presentation logic is kept separated from the page presentation logic.

have a look at the following post:

[MVP and UserControls and invocation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/429500/mvp-and-usercontrols-and-invocation)

Comment: That's the answer I was expecting after a few chats with people - thank you for confirming :)

Comment: Could you please answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8851933/event-bubbling-and-mvp-asp-net  ?